# Is it necessary that garbage collector works only in heap?

Tags: java, jvm

Is it necessary that `garbage collector` works only in `heap`? then what about the method area? I know about the garbage collector that it removes the garbage from heap area of the memory.

Comment: What is the "method area"? Do you have a reference to the JVM Spec that defines this term?

Comment: If by 'method area' you mean the place where the code is, code isn't garbage-collected until the entire class is, which requires the class-loader to be collectible as a precondition. If you mean the stack frame of an executing method, there is nothing there except primitives and references, so no garbage to be collected at all. In short your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *necessary* that it only works in the heap.  But it doesn't make sense for it to function in the stack (or, as you put it, the "*method area*").  Memory allocated on the stack is freed as soon as the method returns.

So, considering this, what would you want the garbage collector to *do* in the stack?  While in theory you might want it to free memory in an extremely long-running method, in the vast majority of cases the method will return long before the garbage collector gets around to looking at it.  Computers are fast.  Plus, if you're holding on to data in a long-running method, chances are there's still a reference to it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The method area gets cleaned up automatically when the call stack pops a method frame upon the method's exit